# Collapse Generator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

So I have a function like this:

```
def demo_range(limit):
    value = 0
    while value < limit:
        yield value
        value = value + 1
```

and this

```
def demo_generator_to_list(generator):
    return [x for x in range(generator)]
```

Now in the `demo_generator_to_list(generator)` I need to fill some code to collapse a generator to:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

from

```
demo_generator_to_list(demo_range(4))
```

Comment: I have *no idea* what you are asking for here. Perhaps you can give us a description of the expected output?

Comment: I need to write code to form a list of the results generated by a generator

Comment: `[x for x in range(generator)]` does not make sense. Did you mean `[x for x in generator]`?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the generator to a `list()` call:

```
def demo_generator_to_list(generator):
    return list(generator)
```

The `list()` function will iterate over the generator and add all results to a new list object.

You could still use a list comprehension, but then you don't use `range()`:

```
return [x for x in generator]
```

This has no advantage over using `list()`; it is just slower.